# Null pointer searching findViewById android app Java

Tags: java, android, eclipse

### problem

Hello, I am having an issue referencing a button on an android app I am making. The issue is a null pointer on referencing the button and I'm rather confused as to why that is occurring. A very similar reference worked on another class and I have included that for reference (onTestButtonClickr of welcomeScreen.java)

## edit

I found that if I change setContentView(R.layout.activity_in_game); to setContentView(R.layout.fragment_in_game); the null pointer goes away but then any changes I make to the button do not work

### logcat

```
04-14 13:13:40.280: D/dalvikvm(838): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
04-14 13:13:43.330: D/dalvikvm(838): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 72K, 5% free 2993K/3132K, paused 167ms, total 169ms
04-14 13:13:44.280: D/dalvikvm(838): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 5% free 3382K/3524K, paused 154ms, total 154ms
04-14 13:13:45.310: D/dalvikvm(838): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8K, 3% free 3802K/3916K, paused 194ms, total 194ms
04-14 13:13:45.590: D/gralloc_goldfish(838): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-14 13:13:59.570: I/Choreographer(838): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-14 13:14:01.030: D/AndroidRuntime(838): Shutting down VM
04-14 13:14:01.030: W/dalvikvm(838): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2aabba8)
04-14 13:14:01.080: E/AndroidRuntime(838): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-14 13:14:01.080: E/AndroidRuntime(838): Process: com.moconnell.thehacker, PID: 838
04-14 13:14:01.080: E/AndroidRuntime(838): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.moconnell.thehacker/com.moconnell.thehacker.InGame}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-14 13:14:01.080: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-14 13:14:01.080: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-14 13:14:01.080: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-14 13:14:01.080: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-14 13:14:01.080: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-14 13:14:01.080: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-14 13:14:01.080: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-14 13:14:01.080: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-14 13:14:01.080: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-14 13:14:01.080: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-14 13:14:01.080: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-14 13:14:01.080: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-14 13:14:01.080: E/AndroidRuntime(838): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-14 13:14:01.080: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at com.moconnell.thehacker.InGame.generateImages(InGame.java:195)
04-14 13:14:01.080: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at com.moconnell.thehacker.InGame.onCreate(InGame.java:64)
04-14 13:14:01.080: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-14 13:14:01.080: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-14 13:14:01.080: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-14 13:14:01.080: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  ... 11 more
04-14 13:14:03.760: I/Process(838): Sending signal. PID: 838 SIG: 9
```

### class with error

```
package com.moconnell.thehacker;

import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Build;


public class InGame extends ActionBarActivity {
    //public ImageButton mBtn;
    ImageButton currentImage;
    //public ArrayList<Drawable> j;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_in_game);

        //mBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ImageButton1_2);
        //mBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.fat_banana);

//      
//
//      btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//          @Override
//          public void onClick(View v) {
//              btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
//              //evaluateSubmission(v);
//          }
//      });



//      
//      Resources resources = com.moconnell.thehacker.WelcomeScreen.getResources();
//       j= new ArrayList<Drawable>();
//       j.add(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.a_button));
//       j.add(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.b_button));
//       j.add(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.c_button));
//       j.add(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.d_button));
//       j.add(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.e_button));
//      
        generateImages();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.in_game, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_in_game,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    //final TextView txtDir = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDirections);
    public void onTestButtonClickr(View view) 
    {

        startActivity(new Intent("com.moconnell.thehacker.WelcomeScreen"));

    }
    public void click(View v)
    {
        //txtDir.setText("eed");//startActivity(new Intent("com.moconnell.thehacker.InGame"));

    }

    public void evaluateButton(View view) 
    {
         ImageButton b = (ImageButton)view;

         currentImage = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ImageButton1_6);
            Log.v("", "currentImage:" + currentImage.getResources());
         //Log.v("", "buttnID:" + b.getId());
         if( b.getId()==R.id.ImageButton1_5)
             Log.v("", "1,5");
         if( b.getId()==R.id.ImageButton2_5)
             Log.v("", "2,5");
         if( b.getId()==R.id.ImageButton3_5)
             Log.v("", "3,5");
         //Log.v("","buttonpressed:"+ b.getdi);



    }

    public void generateImages() 
    {


        ImageButton b16 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ImageButton1_6);


        Log.v("", "b16:" + b16.toString());
        Log.v("", "pic:" + com.moconnell.thehacker.WelcomeScreen.j.get(1));


        // b12.setImageDrawable(com.moconnell.thehacker.WelcomeScreen.j.get(1));

\
         //int id = getResources().getIdentifier("thehacker/drawable/" + "a_button.png", null, null); 
        // b12.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.e_button));
        //b13.setImageResource(id);
        // b14.setImageDrawable(j.get(2));
//      Log.v("", b13.toString());
//      Log.v("", j.get(1));


    }

}
```

### other class that works for reference

```
package com.moconnell.thehacker;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.os.Build;

public class WelcomeScreen extends ActionBarActivity {


    public Button btnNewGame; 
    public Button mBtn;
    public static ArrayList<Drawable> j;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        btnNewGame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNewGame);
        //btnNewGame.setOnClickListener(this);
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//      Button toggleButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHighScore);
//      final ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
//        toggleButton.setOnClickListener(
//
//        new View.OnClickListener() {
//
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//              img.setImageResource(R.drawable.fat_banana);
//            }
//
//        });
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


        Resources resources = getResources();
         j= new ArrayList<Drawable>();
         j.add(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.a_button));
         j.add(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.b_button));
         j.add(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.c_button));
         j.add(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.d_button));
         j.add(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.e_button));



        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    public void onTestButtonClick(View view) 
    {
        startActivity(new Intent("com.moconnell.thehacker.InGame"));
    }   

    public void highScores(View view) 
    {

    }   

    public void onTestButtonClickr(View view) 
    {

         Button b = (Button)view;
         String buttonText = b.getText().toString();
         Log.v("", "butText:" + buttonText);
         b.setText("cc");


         Log.v("", "buttnID:" + b.getId());
         if( b.getId()==R.id.btnNewGame)
             Log.v("", "thsi is the new game button");
         if( b.getId()==R.id.btnHighScore)
             Log.v("", "thsi is the high scores button");

         ImageView i = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
        // .setImageResource(R.drawable.fat_banana);
         Log.v("", "dispImg:" + i.getId());
         Resources resources = getResources();
         //i.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.fat_banana));

         i.setImageDrawable(j.get(1));
        // if(buttonText.equals("View High Scores"))
            //   startActivity(new Intent("com.moconnell.thehacker.InGame"));
    }   

//  private void empezarNewGame()
//  {
//      
//  }
//  


}
```

### fragment_ingame

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:background="@drawable/background_tron"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.moconnell.thehacker.WelcomeScreen"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" 
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonReturn"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            android:onClick="onTestButtonClickr"
             />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="53dp"
            android:onClick="click"
            android:src="@drawable/a_button" 
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton1_6"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/a_display" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton2_6"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/b_display" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton3_6"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/c_display" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton4_6"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/d_display" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton5_6"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/e_display" />

        </TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDirections"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Enter the above code open lock"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/TableRow02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton1_5"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/loading" 
                android:onClick="evaluateButton"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton2_5"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/loading" 
                android:onClick="evaluateButton"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton3_5"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/loading"
                android:onClick="evaluateButton" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton4_5"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/loading" 
                android:onClick="evaluateButton"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton5_5"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/loading" 
                android:onClick="evaluateButton"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/TableRow03"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton1_4"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/loading"
                android:onClick="evaluateButton" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton2_4"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/loading"
                android:onClick="evaluateButton" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton3_4"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/loading"
                android:onClick="evaluateButton" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton4_4"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/loading"
                android:onClick="evaluateButton" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton5_4"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/loading"
                android:onClick="evaluateButton" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton1_3"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/loading" 
                android:onClick="evaluateButton"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton2_3"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/loading" 
                android:onClick="evaluateButton"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton3_3"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/loading"
                android:onClick="evaluateButton" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton4_3"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/loading"
                android:onClick="evaluateButton" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton5_3"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/loading" 
                android:onClick="evaluateButton"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton1_2"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/loading" 
                android:onClick="evaluateButton"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton2_2"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/loading"
                android:onClick="evaluateButton" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton3_2"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/loading" 
                android:onClick="evaluateButton"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton4_2"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/loading" 
                android:onClick="evaluateButton"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton5_2"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/loading"
                android:onClick="evaluateButton" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

### activity_inGame

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.moconnell.thehacker.InGame"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

Comment: please write code for R.layout.activity_in_game class too.

Comment: check if the button belongs to fragment layout . After the adt updatelot of developers make that mistake . initialize fragment views in activity.

Comment: Need to see the code for `R.layout.activity_in_game`. My guess is you have no view defined with ID `R.id.ImageButton1_6`

Comment: I was under the impression I should be using .fragment to design the displays. It has worked thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately the issue was I was editing the fragment and the referring to the activity. Was to replace the welcome screen class line that states:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

to one reflecting of the xml i was editing. Like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_in_game);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling  generateImages() function before fragment with view resource fragment_ingame is attached. So in generateImages() there is no ImageButton is avaiable having id R.id.ImageButton1_6.

Comment: how could I reorder everything for it to fall into proper place?

Comment: You can call generateImages()  method before return statement in onCreateView() method or you can override onViewCreated() or other callback methods that  are called after onCreateView of fragment and call your generateImages() in that method.

Comment: but onCreate() is void, it has no return

Comment: Try this:
public void generateImages( View parent) {
        ImageButton b16 = (ImageButton)parent.findViewById(R.id.ImageButton1_6);
        // write your code
    }

      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_in_game,container, false);
            evaluateButton(rootView) ;
            return rootView;
        }